# Unable to convert .py script to .exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have installed pyinstaller. It supports python 3.6. But still if i run this command i am getting warnings everytime. The .exe file is not being created. How to do that?

I am getting warning like:

```
    516808 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\akhil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\lxml\etree.cp36-win32.pyd
517650 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\akhil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\lxml\etree.cp36-win32.pyd
519292 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\akhil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\lxml\etree.cp36-win32.pyd
520278 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\akhil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\
lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp36-win32.pyd
521404 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\akhil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\l
ib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp36-win32.pyd
```

How to resolve this and make a .exe file? I have done this using cx_Freeze also.But still, no use.

Comment: You need to install the Universal C Runtime for windows, it comes with visual studio.

Comment: But visual studio is already installed in mine. Still same problem exists.

Comment: Then you may need to find a place to download it seperately, but those missing dll files are associated with the C Runtime for windows.

Comment: can you please share the link for the download?